# PHP Execution times causing response delays

Tags: php, apache, execution-time

I am intentionally running a php script that last up to 60 seconds on my server with a delay between each run. The issue is that any other requests sent to the server while the script is executing are delayed until the script finishes.

Is there anyway to 'thread'(?) php to allow apache to take requests that require php while the script is running?

Comment: This is actually a question for probably http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ . StackOverflow is really about programming, not tuning your webserver.

Comment: I assume the issue is with my code, I'm a really sloppy developer...

Answer (score 1):

Apache and PHP will by default serve many concurrent connections just fine. I'll take a stab into the dark and guess that you are **starting a session**. The default session handler is file based, and will acquire an exclusive lock on the session file, which blocks all concurrent requests that try to use that same session file. Close the session before you go off doing long-running tasks with [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/session_write_close).

Comment: The code doesn't use a session at all, it does however use the same mysql connection, could this be the source?

Comment: "The same"? Unless it's a persistent connection with a really small pool, that should not be the reason either. If it's not sessions, which is the most typical problem, then you'll have to provide more information about your server configuration and on what exactly you're doing.